# converting multiple BAM files to BED files

Tags: shell, bioinformatics, bam, bedtools

I have BAM files in the external hard drive. Want to convert them into BED.
Am using

```
cd /media/amit/LaCie/mdc_work/chigozie/pool1/bam
for x in *.bam ; do
    echo "print current:$x";
    bedtools bamToBed -i "$x" > "${x%.bam}.bed";
done
echo "done"
```

it writes the BED files in the directory, but they are all empty. My BEDtools is installed in

```
/home/amit/miniconda3/bin/bedtools
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?
regards.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/473555/  : the command should be `bamtobed`.

Answer (score 0):

Empty `bed` files could be caused by `bam` files with no reads. The `bam` files could still have non-zero file size due to headers. Find the number of reads in the `bam` file using `samtools`:

```
samtools view -c input.bam
```

or `sambamba`:

```
sambamba view -c input.bam
```

This should output into STDIN the number of reads in the `bam` file. Both of these could be installed using `conda`, for example like so:

```
conda create -n my_env_name samtools sambamba
```